# Placing stop-limit using high[n]

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to place a stop-limit order, a market buy order would be placed if price goes above high[1] + high[1]/2 but the order never gets placed

```
strategy.order(id = "Long", long = true,stop=high[1]+(high[1]/2))
```

for instance if previous candle high is 200 then order should be placed if price crosses 300 => 200 + 200/2

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there were such conditions like you're looking for in the whole history? Maybe I don't understand what you exactly want, but look at the next code:

```
//@version=3
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true)
 // high[1] * 1.1 would be easier to read
strategy.order(id = "Long", long = true,when=close > high[1] + high[1] / 10.0)
strategy.exit("exit", from_entry="Long", stop= high[1] + high[1] / 10.0)
```

In my opinion it does what you're looking for (but enstead 1.5 of previous high, it uses 1.1)